# Flutter timer.periodic is slower than real life

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile-development, flutter-timer

I am using timer.periodic to call some functions at different times. The problem which I am facing is that the timer is much slower than real life like for example what you will see in my code that the timer should finish in 5 seconds but in real life its taking 25 seconds to finish.

```
 void startTheTimer(){
    var counter = 5;
    final zeroDurationTimer = Timer.run(() {
      _StartDataCollection();
    });
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      print(timer.tick);
      counter--;
      if (counter == 2) {
        _StopDataCollection();
      }else if (counter == 1){
        createUser();
      }
      if (counter == 0) {
        print('Cancel timer');
        timer.cancel();
        print(numbers.length);
        print(fifo.length);
      }
    });
  }
```

the print on the compiler shows the timer ticks as 1-2-3-4-5 but its taking it too long to print 2 and then same goes for the rest of the ticks.
Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: Why should it finish in 5 seconds? It is doing 5 iterations of 5 seconds so it should finish in 5 x 5s = 25s, right?

Comment: Thats what I want to do. I want it to work only one time. Can you point me to what am i doing wrong

Comment: You can use `Future.delayed` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) { //do function }` mean, it spent **5s** to do this function

So, if you do this function **5 times**, it will spent **25s**

Change to **1s** will work:

```
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      print(timer.tick);
      counter--;
      if (counter == 2) {
        _StopDataCollection();
      }else if (counter == 1){
        createUser();
      }
      if (counter == 0) {
        print('Cancel timer');
        timer.cancel();
        print(numbers.length);
        print(fifo.length);
      }
    });
```

or use **for-loop** instead **timer**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      counter--;
      print(counter);
      if (counter == 2) {
        _StopDataCollection();
      }else if (counter == 1){
        createUser();
      }
      if (counter == 0) {
        print('Cancel timer');
        print(numbers.length);
        print(fifo.length);
      }
    }
```